# SASS - [dir="rtl"] not being applied

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have a thumbnail with an icon that needs to be adjusted for RTL. The original position for this icon differs a bit from desktop to mobile.

I'm quite new to SASS so I'm having trouble applying the `[dir="rtl"]` rule to both of these situations.

This is what I have so far:

```
.cell {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.thumbnail {
    position: relative;

    .icon {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        color: white;

        [dir="rtl"] & { // working
            right: 10px;
            left: unset;
        }
    }
}

@include respond-to(mobile) {
    ...

    .icon {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 7px;
        left: 7px;

        [dir="rtl"] & { // not working
            right: 7px;
            left: unset;
        }
    }
}
```

The HTML for desktop:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!platform.isMobileSize()">
    <div class="cell" [gbDirRtl]="isRTL">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="thumbnail-image" [style.background-image]="thumbnail | backgroundimage"></div>
            <div class="icon" gbIcon [iconUrl]="icon" [size]="24"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="section-name"
                 [gbFontStyle]="subtitleFont"
            >{{formattedSubtitle}}</div>
            <div class="title"
                [gbFontStyle]="titleFont"
                gbLineClamp="3"
            >{{item.title}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

The HTML for mobile:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="platform.isMobileSize()">
    <gb-classic-list-cell>
        <gb-background-image [src]="mobileThumbnail" [height]="'100%'" [useBackgroundImage]="true">
            <div class="icon" gbIcon [iconUrl]="icon" [size]="20" [color]="'#ffffff'"></div>
        </gb-background-image>
        <div class="heading" [gbFontStyle]="titleFont">{{ item.title }}</div>
        <div class="sub-heading" *ngIf="showInfos" [gbFontStyle]="subtitleFont">{{ formattedSubtitle }}</div>
    </gb-classic-list-cell>
    <div class="overlay" [class.visible]="showOverlay || isSelected">
        <gb-bookmark-checkbox [checked]="isSelected" (tap)="toggle()"></gb-bookmark-checkbox>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

The normal one is working but the mobile one is not. I know that the first one is targeting `[dir="rtl"] .thumbnail .icon` so it has priority over `[dir="rtl"] .icon` but I can't come up with a solution where both situations work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you figure out the fix for this? I am facing the same issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

A little more context on how you've written your HTML file would've helped.

Could you check if either of these work.

```css
.icon {
  /* styles */
  
  &[dir="rtl"] {
    /* styles */
  }
}

/* OR */

.icon {
  /*styles*/
  & [dir="rtl"] {
  /*styles*/
  }
}
```

Comment: These are not working unfortunately. I updated the question with the HTML.